# props están definidas al prinicipio pero después son undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate

tengo un componente `Header` en la que tengo un array de objetos que uso para guardar los textos e iconos de los enlaces de la barra de navegación:

Esta es la lista:

```javascript
    const headerLinks = [
        {
            title: "Features",
            hasMenu: true,
            menuItems: [
                {
                    title: "Todo List", 
                    icon: "icon-todo.svg"
                },
                {
                    title: "Calendar",
                    icon: "icon-calendar.svg"
                },
                {
                    title: "Reminders",
                    icon: "icon-reminders.svg"
                },
                {
                    title: "Planning",
                    icon: "icon-planning.svg"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            title: "Company",
            hasMenu: true,
            menuItems: [
                {
                    title: "History"
                },
                {
                    title: "Our Team"
                },
                {
                    title: "Blog"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            title: "Careers",
            hasMenu: false,
        },
        {
            title: "About",
            hasMenu: false,
        }
    ]
```

El componente `Header` está definido así:

```
    <header>
        <nav className="flex">
            <div className="logo-links flex">
                <img src="logo.svg" alt="logo" className="logo"/>
                <ul className="header-links flex">
                    {myHeaderLinks.map((link, i) => 
                        (
                           <li key={i}>
                               <HeaderDropdown 
                                   title={link.title} 
                                   hasMenu={link.hasMenu} 
                                   menuItems={link.menuItems}
                               />
                           </li>
                         ))
                     }
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="account-links flex">
                <button className="login-btn">Login</button>
                <button className="signup-btn">Register</button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Como se observa, recorro el array con un `map` y por cada link regreso un nuevo componente `HeaderDropdown`, con las props title, hasMenu y menuItems, que serían los links del menu desplegable, es un array. Cuando intento hacer un console.log() de este array desde el componente `HeaderDropdown` al principio aparecen en consola, pero después aparece `undefined`, y cuando intento acceder ellos no puedo hacerlo.
Esto es lo que me sale en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuál puede ser el error ?

Comment: Tanto a __Careers__,__About__ asignales el valor de `menuItems: []`. Y de mejor forma agrega un condicional para que renderice solo cuando tiene valores __menuItems__

Comment: Efectivamente era eso, no me habia dado cuenta pero trataba de acceder a los menuItems cuando algunos elementos no tenian, ademas de agregarles el array vacio tambien utilice el renderizado condicional, gracias !